# CSS Position In SlideBar

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox, tailwind-css

I am using Tailwind with reactJS,
I have 2 different jsx file i.e Navpanel.jsx & Home.jsx

When I used fixed Position **Home Text** is going in navpanel. I also use block instead of flex but Navpanel then cover entire screen.
Please give me solution.

```
function Navpanel() {
  return (
    <div className="fixed flex h-full w-1/5 overflow-hidden from-gray-800 to-blue-800 before:h-full before:absolute before:w-screen before:bg-gradient-to-r before:content-[''] before:-z-10"></div>
  )
}
```

```
function Home() {
  return (
    <div className='flex relative'>Home</div>
  )
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Keep the nav and the below nav component in `App.js` file. You can write you app.js file like this

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <>
    <div className="max-h-screen w-full">
      <Navbar />
      <div className="flex items-center w-full" >
        <SidePanel />
        <HomePage />
      </div>  
    </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default App;
```

And inside `home page` component you can define any thing you want .

You can take refer from below example

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="max-h-screen h-full w-full">
  <div class="flex items-center w-full ">
    <div class="w-1/3 h-screen bg-rose-500">Side Panel</div>
    <div class="w-2/3 h-screen bg-blue-500">Home Panel</div>
  </div>
</div>
```